# Mapping a CGPoint in RestKit from two different keys

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

I have some JSON I'm getting, and I'm mapping it to my object. Most of the properties I have set up for that class have a simple one-to-one relationship, but there is an exception. This is the relevant JSON:

```
{
  "image_id":"2",
  "title":"Test Pic",
  "x":"49",
  "y":"186"
}
```

In my corresponding Objective-C class I have 3 properties, an `NSNumber`, an `NSString`, and a `CGPoint` which is intended to hold the `x` and the `y` values. I'm mapping them as such:

```
RKObjectMapping *imageMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Image class]];
[imageMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"image_id", @"title"]];
```

But I'm stumped on how to get the `x` and `y` into a single CGPoint struct. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it directly as the CGPoint contents can't be modified by KVC.

You can add 2 accessor methods, `setPointX:` and `setPointY:`, to the `Image` class which each set the appropriate part of the `CGPoint`, and use `pointX` and `pointY` in your mappings because this is KVC compliant.